# Idiomatic way to define auto-populated columns with TypeORM

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I'm working on a project that uses TypeScript (with NestJS & TypeORM). I'm trying to find out what is the best way to define columns which are populated by the DB or TypeORM in a way that is type safe.

For example the decorator [@PrimaryGeneratedColumn](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/decorator-reference#primarygeneratedcolumn) or [@UpdateDateColumn](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/decorator-reference#updatedatecolumn) automatically sets the values on a column. The (merged) examples on the docs would be

```
@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    id: string;

    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updatedDate: Date;
}
```

The example is a bit misleading as TypeORM would suggest to create a User instance without a value for the columns (as it's later set automatically). So what would be the correct way to define an entity like this? Would one need to define the type as optional or `xxx | undefined`?

I have the impression that TypeORM often clashes against the type system in TS.